# Storm emitting array of integers and retrieving it

Tags: java, arrays, apache-storm, emit

I'm turning an image to a 2D array of integers. Doing some process on that then I'm trying to emit the array in this way :

```
collector.emit( new Values ( scaledImageMatrix ) );
```

then I'm trying to retrieve the data in another bolt like this :

```
int [][] imageMatrix = input.get("scaled-image-matrix");
```

but I get the error

```
incompatible types
[ERROR] found   : java.lang.Object
[ERROR] required: int[][]
```

Any suggestions ?

UPDATE :

I tried this `int [][] imageMatrix = (int[][])input.get("scaled-image-matrix");`

and I got this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tuple created with wrong number of fields. Expected 1 fields but got 190 fields
```

Then I should change my question to : How to emit a two dimensional array ?

Comment: Now I got this error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tuple created with wrong number of fields. Expected 1 fields but got 190 fields`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that's not possible except building a serializer yourself for two-dimensional array.

Storm will try to guess the type of a tuple and see if it can be serialized. Anything emitted is already serialized, so there's no way to send any object storm can't serialize.

> By default, Storm can serialize primitive types, strings, byte arrays, ArrayList, HashMap, HashSet, and the Clojure collection types.

So I suggest use `ArrayList` or Clojure's `vector` instead, or write a custom [kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) serializer by yourself. See the docs [here](https://storm.incubator.apache.org/documentation/Serialization.html).

Answer (score 2):

I know it's old question but this can be also useful. Primitive array can be emitted and received in the `execute(Tuple input)` method like any other object, you just need to use `getValue(fieldName)` method instead of `get(fieldName)`:

```
int[][] imageMatrix = (int[][]) input.getValue("scaled-image-matrix")
```